# UIImage overlaps with UITextField within a UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My code is this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "alert", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let image_view = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(70, 10, 200, 200))
image_view.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
alert.view.addSubview(image_view)
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in textField.placeholder = "a textfield"
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in textField.placeholder = "another textfield" }
```

Yet this results in my logo overlapping with the UITextFields. How can I make sure that they are neatly stacked one below the other??

Comment: You have not set the frame for textfield.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view if you would like to create `UIAlertController` with custom UI try to create it by you're own. Or if you would like to use a bit hacky solution like this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "logo")
alert.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
```

Comment: I get a `setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image` with this

Answer (score 0):

Try setting frame to the textfield:-

```
    var textField = UITextField()        
    textField.frame = CGRect(x: , y: image_view.bounds.minY + 10, width: 250, height: 40)
    textField.placeholder = "a textfield"
    alertController.view.addSubview(textField)
```

Setting Frame worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to design your custom alert controller [example](https://github.com/anas10/AABlurAlertController)
Because `UIAlertController` has limited below functionality

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
open class UIAlertController : UIViewController {


    public convenience init(title: String?, message: String?, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle)


    open func addAction(_ action: UIAlertAction)

    open var actions: [UIAlertAction] { get }


    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    open var preferredAction: UIAlertAction?


    open func addTextField(configurationHandler: ((UITextField) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)

    open var textFields: [UITextField]? { get }


    open var title: String?

    open var message: String?


    open var preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle { get }
}
```